# python buckw kill error while building selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, buck

I'm trying to build selenium webdriver project using the command "go" in Rakefile location but it got aborted with below error,

Note : Java version is 1.8 and Python version is 2.7

### Error:

```
$ python buckw kill
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buckw", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
Exception `RuntimeError' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1c84d80a>>' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1c84d80a>>' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1c84d80a>>' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1c84d80a>>' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1c84d80a>>' at uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66 - Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
go aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [python buckw kill...]
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_shell_runner'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:35:in `sh'
C:/Location/GitHub/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:17:in `download'
C:/Location/GitHub/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:24:in `buck_cmd'
C:/Location/GitHub/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:227:in `block in (root)'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in `each'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in `each'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in `each'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:973:in `load'
uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/bin/rake:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test => test_javascript => //javascript/atoms:atoms-chrome:run => //javascript/atoms:atoms-chrome
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this:

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I would suggest you install `requests` and try again:

```
pip install requests
```